# как добавить autoprefixer?

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js

Подскажите, как добавить в vue-cli ( webpack-simple ) autoprefixer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Открываем документацию

https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/blob/master/docs/en/options.md#postcss

И видим

```
{
  loader: 'vue-loader',
  options: {
    // note: do not nest the `postcss` option under `loaders`
    postcss: [require('postcss-cssnext')()],
    loaders: {
      // ...
    }
  }
}
```

Повторяем пример из документации и устанавливаем `npm i postcss-cssnext -D`

Запускаем и видим что все работает, префиксы вплоть до `-ms`.

Как добавить нужные, к примеру так.

```
postcss: [require('postcss-cssnext')({ browsers: ['last 1 versions'] })]
```